# Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

Suppose that you are trying to buy a car, and a car is either in good condition (with $80\%$ probability) or in bad bad condition (with $20\%$ probability). You can inspect the car first, and this inspection has an accuracy of $80\%$, i.e. if the inspector says the car is in good condition, then the car is in good condition $80\%$ of the time, and so is if the inspector says the car is in bad condition.

I would like to know what the probability of the inspector saying the car is good is (I'm not actually sure if this is possible with the information given).

My attempt at solving the problem is as follows. Let

- $A:=$ the car is good and
- $B:=$ the inspector says the car is good.

Our premises tell us that $\Pr(A)=0.8$, $\Pr(A\mid B)=0.8$ and $\Pr(A^c\mid B^c)=0.8$. By the law of total probability we have:

\begin{align}
\Pr(A)&=\Pr(A\mid B)\Pr(B)+\Pr(A\mid B^c)\Pr(B^c)\\[0.2cm]
0.8&=0.8\Pr(B)+0.2(1-\Pr(B))\\[0.2cm]
1&=\Pr(B)
\end{align}

But intuitively this doesn't seem right to me... and I can't for the life of me figure out where I'm making an incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a sample space of 100 cars. There will be 80 good and 20 bad. The inspector is wrong 20% of the time. He/she will say 20% good cars are bad, and 20% bad cars are good. Thus the inspector says there are 64 good and 16 bad for the 80 actually good cars; and says there are 16 bad and 4 are good for the 20 actually bad cars. The inspector will say 64+4 good cars and 16+16 bad cars, giving a probability of 68/100.